# How do we calculate the isotropic curvature is nonnegative on a $4$-dimensional manifold?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

How do we calculate the isotropic curvature is nonnegative on a four dimension manifold? Do we verify it on any orthogonal basis?

Answer (score 5):

It's not always easy to find in the various references, but there is a fairly explicit criterion to check this on a Riemannian $4$-manifold that does not require that one actually compute the isotropic curvature in every isotropic $2$-plane.  For example, while it is not obvious from the definition, the isotropic curvature only depends on the scalar curvature and the Weyl curvature; the traceless Ricci curvature does not enter into the final formula.

For simplicity, assume that $M^4$ is oriented (though the final answer will not depend on the orientation).  Then the $2$-form bundle $\Lambda^2(TM)$ splits into two $3$-plane bundles $\Lambda^2_\pm(TM)$ of self-dual ($+$) and anti-self-dual ($-$) bivectors.  Then the Riemann curvature $R:\Lambda^2\to\Lambda^2$ has the Singer-Thorpe decomposition
$$
R = \left(\frac{S}{12}\right)\,\mathrm{id} + W_+ + W_- + Q + Q^*
$$
where $S$ is the scalar curvature, the symmetric maps $W_\pm:\Lambda^2_\pm\to\Lambda^2_\pm$ are traceless, and $Q:\Lambda^2_+\to\Lambda^2_-$.  (In this formulation $W_\pm$ are the self-dual and anti-self-dual components of the Weyl curvature while $Q$ is equivalent to the traceless Ricci curvature.)

In these terms, letting $\lambda(W_\pm)\ge 0$ denote the (pointwise) maximum eigenvalue of $W_\pm$ as a function on $M$ (nonnegative because the trace of $W_\pm$ vanishes), it turns out that the metric has nonnegative isotropic curvature if and only if
$$
S\ge 6\lambda(W_\pm)
$$
Note that, because this condition is unchanged by reversing the orientation of $M$, it is actually well-defined even for unoriented Riemannian $4$-manifolds.

Positive isotropic curvature is equivalent to $S>6\lambda(W_\pm)$.

Comment: I assume it's a typo, but the condition for non-negative isotropic curvature and PIC seems inconsistent.

Comment: @RBega2:  Thanks, you are right.  I missed the '6' in the final inequality.  I've fixed that now.

Comment: Thank you very much!